# Is there a common interface for Windows Forms for the Enable and Visible properties?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to create the class `UserAction`. This class accepts a collection of widgets and a callback. The main idea is to have a common object in which you can put various widgets enabled or disabled (or visible/invisible).

For example, for *saveAction*, an object of class `UserAction`, you would like to add *opSave* (a `ToolStripMenuItem`), and *tbbSave* (a `ToolStripButton`).

```
this.saveAction = new UserAction( this.OnSave );
this.saveAction.AddControl( this.opSave );
this.loadAction.AddControl( this.tbbSave );
```

When you put the *Enabled* property of the `saveAction` to `false`...

```
saveAction.Enabled = false;
```

the saveAction should run all over the controls over the collection and put all their `Enabled` properties to *false*.

The problem is that `Control`, which at first seems to be the most common root class, includes *Enabled* and *Visible*, though unfortunately is not the root class for `ToolStrip-whatever` class. The common class is `Component`. And it does not include those properties.

The (ugly) code I have written is:

```
class UserAction {
    // ...
    public void SetControlsEnabled(bool value)
    {
            foreach(Component cmp in this.controls) {
                var c = cmp as Control;
                var tsi = cmp as ToolStripItem;

                if ( c != null ) {
                    c.Enabled = value;
                }
                else
                if ( tsi != null ) {
                    tsi.Enabled = value;
                }
           }

           return;
    }

    public bool Enabled {
        // ...
        set {
            this.SetControlsEnabled( value );
        }
    }

    // ...
    private List<Component> components;
}
```

The code for accessing the *Enabled* property is the same one for both cases, but unfortunately there is not a common class or interface defining the properties *Enabled* and *Visible*. Or, at least, I have not been able to find that.

The code above solves the issue for `ToolStrip-whatever` components, and Buttons, and so on... unfortunately the old style menus and toolbar buttons are not covered, I'd have to check for `Menu` and `ToolBarButton` specifically (again, the common ancestor is `Component`, but that class does not define those properties).

Is not there a more clean and general solution available?

Comment: I know its ugly but you can use `dynamic` and let `Enabled` and `Visible` resolve in runtime. Seeing your current code you *know* that all elements in `Controls` will have shuch properties so its safe enough; just change your `foreach(Component cmp in this.Controls)` to `foreach(dynamic cmp in this.Controls)`

Comment: Very high odds that you are writing unnecessary code.  Setting the Enabled/Visible property affects not just the control but all of its children as well, without you having to set the property on the children.  True for Menu and toolstrip items as well, simply setting the ToolStrip or MenuStrip's properties is enough.

Comment: @HansPassant While you're right, I think this code makes sense if OP wants to disable/enable two or more unrelated controls. I mean when no parent child relation exist.

Comment: Well, it doesn't make sense because he sets the property on *every* toolstrip item.  So just setting it on the ToolStrip is enough.

Comment: @HansPassant, I don't think you undestand what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @InBetween, this is certainly a possibility. Why didn't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Well, this site is about giving solutions...doesn't really make a difference if it's via comments or answers does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already suggested:

```
foreach(dynamic cmp in this.controls)
{
    cmp.Enabled = value;
}
```

Comment: For future readers: `dynamic` is a good recipe to defer problems in your code. So think twice before you use it.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one more level of abstraction. That will eliminate the ugly code and really make it better.

```
class UserAction
{
    public void SetControlsEnabled(bool value)
    {
        foreach (ISupportEnabled component in this.components)
        {
            component.Enabled = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        // ...
        set
        {
            this.SetControlsEnabled(value);
        }
    }

    private List<ISupportEnabled> components = new List<ISupportEnabled>();

    public void AddComponent(ISupportEnabled component)
    {
        if (!components.Contains(component))
        {
            components.Add(component);
        }
    }
}

public interface ISupportEnabled
{
    bool Enabled { get; set; }
}

private class ControlAdapter : ISupportEnabled
{
    private readonly Control control;

    public ControlAdapter(Control control)
    {
        this.control = control;
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return control.Enabled; }
        set { control.Enabled = value; }
    }
}

private class ToolStripItemAdapter : ISupportEnabled
{
    private readonly ToolStripItem toolStripItem;
    public ToolStripItemAdapter(ToolStripItem toolStripItem)
    {
        this.toolStripItem = toolStripItem;
    }

    public bool Enabled
    {
        get { return toolStripItem.Enabled; }
        set { toolStripItem.Enabled = value; }
    }
}
```

Then use it as

```
UserAction userAction = new UserAction();
userAction.AddComponent(new ControlAdapter(this.MyTextBox));
userAction.AddComponent(new ToolStripItemAdapter(this.MyToolStripItem));
```

Else where in the code:

```
userAction.Enabled = false;
```

I hope you got the Idea, if some more classes needs to be used this way, you need to create a new adapter for that and that's it. If you want you can hide the Adapter creation code, you could create a factory which checks the type of the object and returns an adapter for it.

Comment: Your response is great, but I'm still wishing to find something more simple than my code.

I will choose your answer as correct if there is no other possibility.

Comment: @Baltasarq AFAIK there is no abstraction or generic ways to handle them, but yes let's see if someone can bring a better answer. :)